# How to read json.out file from databricks

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, amazon-sagemaker

I have been working with databricks for reading output from Object2Vec in Sagemaker. This output is saved as jsonlines with `.json.out` file format.

```
df_emb = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json(bucket+key)
```

When i read this file as a json, it is read as a corrupt record. Below is the screenshot. 
[image]

I can provide the actual file if you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To parse jsonlines, you should use single-line mode, instead of multi-line mode.

`df_emb = spark.read.option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json(bucket+key)`

See https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-json.html#single-line-mode